# cursor:pointer on hover html5 canvas element

Tags: html, canvas, easeljs, mouse-cursor

Is there any way to do this to let the user know the element is clickable?

I have been using easeljs but haven't found anything related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use this: [How to make clickable points in html5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665862/how-to-make-clickable-points-in-html5-canvas)

and while the mouse is in that area, you can set: `$('#canvasID').css('cursor','pointer')` and `$('#canvasID').css('cursor','auto')` when it's not over it.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Easeljs and to get a pointer cursor I use `myObject.cursor = 'pointer'` and  `stage.enableMouseOver(20);` ( from the DragAndDrop.html example code )